# For Loop based on Variable - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a script task in which I specify the variables like this:

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dts.Variables("sTest").Value = 1

    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
```

The value for the variable is specified from a front-end code.

Next I have a for loop container that internally contains a script task.

I want to pass the variable that is dynamically entered in the external script task into the loop and hence execute a message box defined in the script task.

The message box dynamically shows values as and when specified

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If in the variables task I enter a value I want it to be displayed when the package is run in the "Run to display value as specified in the variables task"

Comment: So you need to know how to display a messagebox?

Comment: Display message in the messagebox that will hold the value specified in the Variables step

Comment: MsgBox(Dts.Variables("sTest").Value)

Comment: Please explaing how to configure the steps...Thanks

Comment: I want the value that is specified in the Variables Step to be displayed in the second Script task when the package is run

Comment: Will this package be run in production i.e. unattended? If so, the MSG box will stop the package from ever completing. Very bad practise